# Simple Injector - Singleton with transient dependency design

Tags: c#, wpf, inversion-of-control, simple-injector

### The context

I know the purpose of SimpleInjector's LifestyleMismatch exception and why it throws it. But suppose to have:

Players.dll

```cs
public abstract class PlayerEqualizer { ... }

public abstract class Player : IPlayer, ISongAware
{
    public Player(PlayerEqualizer eq)
    {
        Equalizer = eq;
    }

    public PlayerEqualizer Equalizer { get; }
    public abstract void StartPlay();
}
```

Players.Rock.dll

```cs
public class RockPlayerEqualizer  : PlayerEqualizer {}

public class RockPlayer : Player
{
    public RockPlayer(RockPlayerEqualizer  eq) : base(eq) {}

    public override void StartPlay() { ... }
}

public class RnBPlayer : Player
{
    public RnBPlayer(RockPlayerEqualizer  eq) : base(eq) {}

    public override void StartPlay() { ... }
}
```

Players.Pop.dll

```cs
public class PopPlayerEqualizer : PlayerEqualizer{}

public class PopPlayer : Player
{
    public PopPlayer(PopPlayerEqualizer eq) : base(eq) {}

    public override void StartPlay() { ... }
}
```

All the implementation of `Player` are registered as a collection of `IPlayer` and all the registrations are singleton:

```cs
var registrations = container
    .GetTypesToRegister(typeof(IPlayer), assemblies)
    .Select(t => Lifestyle.Singleton.CreateRegistration(t, container));


foreach (var registration in registrations)
{
    container.AddRegistration(registration.ImplementationType, registration);
}

container.RegisterCollection<IPlayer>(registrations);
container.RegisterCollection<ISongAware>(container.GetCurrentRegistrations()
    .Where(ip => typeof(ISongAware).IsAssignableFrom(ip.ServiceType))
    .Select(ip => ip.Registration));
```

### The problem

All

- `container.GetInstance<RockPlayer>`
- `container.GetAllInstances<IPlayer>`
- `container.GetAllInstances<ISongAware>`

must return the same instance, so the `IPlayer` registrations must be singleton. Doing so, all the `PlayerEqualizer` must be singleton as well, since they are dependency of a singleton registration, but the `PlayerEqualizer` implementation aren't singleton (`RockPlayer` and `RnBPlayer` both depend on `RockPlayerEqualizer` but they need different instances).

### What I tried

The only solution I could find is to set the SimpleInjector `container.Options.SuppressLifestyleMismatchVerification` flag to `False` but I don't want to lose that feature... Another option could be call the `SuppressDiagnosticWarning` method on the `IPlayer`'s registrations but despite I couldn't get it to work, my real concern is that these solutions are just workaround...

Am I missing something?

Comment: Must must those container methods always return the same instances? (This sounds like an [x-y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/67392) because all the consequences follow from that restriction.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is *not* to register `PlayerEqualizer` instances as [Transient](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetimes.html#transient) but as [Instance Per Dependency](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetimes.html#instance-per-dependency).

Technically, both lifestyles are the same, as they both return new instances on every request. The *intend* of *Instance per Dependency* is however, *very* different, because:

> *Each consumer will get a new instance of the given service type and that dependency is expected to get live as long as its consuming type.*

While with *Transient* the intention is the dependency to be short-lived.

This lifestyle is deliberately left out of Simple Injector, because:

> *its usefulness is very limited compared to the Transient lifestyle. It ignores lifestyle mismatch checks and this can easily lead to errors, and it ignores the fact that application components should be immutable. In case a component is immutable, it’s very unlikely that each consumer requires its own instance of the injected dependency.*

The project's Code Samples however contains the definition of a [InstancePerDependencyLifestyle](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/blob/master/src/SimpleInjector.CodeSamples/InstancePerDependencyLifestyle.cs#L11) that does what you want it do do:

- It gives every consumer its own instance
- It ignores lifestyle mismatches on the registration, since the instance is expected to live as long as its consumer

You can use this lifestyle as follows:

```
container.Register<RockPlayerEqualizer>(new InstancePerDependencyLifestyle());
```

**UPDATE**:

Do note that your configuration can be simplified to the following:

```
var playerTypes = var registrations = container
    .GetTypesToRegister(typeof(IPlayer), assemblies);

foreach (Type playerType in playerTypes)
{
    container.Register(playerType, Lifestyle.Singleton);
}

container.RegisterCollection<IPlayer>(assemblies);
container.RegisterCollection<ISongAware>(assemblies);
```

Comment: Thanks Steven. But I'm wondering if there's a better way to approach this scenario than just get rid of the lifestyle mismatch check...

Comment: It depends. In general you should prefer your components to be stateless and move runtime data through their method calls. This typically simplifies the application a lot and makes it easier to reason about your code. The reason you have this issue is because your `PlayerEqualizer` instances are statefull. But whether creating a stateless design makes sense in your case, I can't tell.